# Proteger a string de conexão em uma aplicação .NET Winforms?

Tags: .net, sql-server, winforms, segurança

Tenho uma aplicação **.NET Windows Forms** que se conecta a um servidor **SQL Server** diretamente, sem o uso de uma camada intermediária como um *WebService* ou *WebAPI*, através de `SqlConnection`. Essa aplicação é instalada no computador dos clientes enquanto o servidor fica disponível através da internet.

Qual a melhor maneira, sem alterar toda a aplicação, de evitar que a string de conexão (*connection string*) seja capturada através de um *sniffer* tipo o **[WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/)** rodando na mesma rede?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifiquei que a versões do SQL antigas, anteriores a 2005 (especificamente a 2000) não funcionam com o parâmetro `encrypt=yes` na string de conexão (*connection string*). Tentei em outro server mais recente e recebi o erro:

> provider: Provedor SSL, error: 0 - A cadeia de certificação foi
>   emitida por uma autoridade que não é de confiança.

Então encontrei outro parâmetro `trustservercertificate=true` que adicionei à minha string de conexão e funcionou. Esse parâmetro permite que meu client aceite um certificado emitido pelo server.

Em testes que fiz com [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) não consegui interceptar nem a string de conexão, nem as instruções SQL, nem os dados de retorno. Os dados agora trafegam criptografados.

Então, a solução que encontrei foi incluir esse trecho ao final da string de conexão:

```
encrypt=yes;trustservercertificate=true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Segundo este [artigo em inglês](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2436/what-does-my-sql-server-data-look-like-over-the-wire/), o componente de conexão do SQL Server já vai criptografar as partes importantes da string de conexão durante a conexão, como a senha e nome de usuário... a não ser que use ODBC.

Seguindo alguns links desse artigo, encontrei esse artigo da MSDN: [Criptografando conexões com o SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189067%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) que **mostra como forçar o uso de SSL para criptografar TODO o tráfego de dados entre o cliente e o servidor SQL Server**.

Comment: Mesmo que o usuário e senha fiquem ocultos, todo o retorno que o banco enviar para a aplicação poderá ser capturado pelo sniffer. Se você fizer um "select * from usuario" vai ser mostrado todos os dados de todos usuários no tráfego recebido mesmo que a aplicação não exiba nenhum desses dados.

Comment: Basta usar SSL, e problema resolvido.

Comment: Fora o trabalho para implementar depois basta usar `SSLstrip` para capturar.

Comment: Isso que o Maicon disse, de que "todos os dados de todos usuários no tráfego" é natural, mesmo com webservices isso acontece. A ideia é evitar que alguém consiga autenticação para manipular os dados fora de sua aplicação. Vou tentar implementar a opção encrypt=yes da connectionString, depois se tiver sucesso volto aqui pra marcar a resposta.

Comment: O SQL Server não usa HTTPS e sim [TSL/SSL](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc784450(v=ws.10).aspx), por isso o SSLStrip não deve conseguir ler as transmissões do SQL Server, pois o segundo [funciona sobre HTTPS](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41988/how-does-sslstrip-work).

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Erro meu quanto ao capturar a conexão criptografada do SQL Server, tinha levado em conta apenas você ter mencionado o uso de SSL. Pelo menos até o momento né huaehaeuhea e ganhou +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

O correto mesmo seria você não ter essa conexão do `cliente -> banco` e sim `cliente -> webService (com autenticação) -> banco`. Por mais que você tente fazer algum tipo de encode/encriptação na string, todo o tráfego feito entre o cliente e o banco poderá ser capturado pelo sniffer. **Qualquer select poderá ser capturado mesmo que sua aplicação não mostre esses dados eles virão no tráfego e podem ser capturados sem dificuldade.**

Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mesmo que tente implementar uma conexão segura, isso poderá ser burlado com o [sslstrip](http://blog.corujadeti.com.br/sslstrip-e-man-in-the-middle-ssl-seguro/). É mais fácil criar um WebService e com isso deixar a comunicação com o banco isolada do cliente.

Comment: Se conseguir evitar que o acesso direto ao banco seja barrado, ou seja, evitar que as informações de autenticação sejam acessíveis, já resolve. Pois mesmo com webservices ou webapis, informações sobre tipos e campos dos dados poderão ser interceptados.

Comment: Também não posso considerar que seja mais fácil implementar com webservice uma aplicação considerável que já está em produção.

Comment: @iuristona Realmente, levando em conta que já está em produção fica difícil de ter todo esse retrabalho. Quanto ao WebServices serem interceptados a diferença é que no WebService você consegue ter um controle de quem requisitou, como enviar, consegue tratar os dados antes de enviar e obstrui qualquer possibilidade do usuário saber a localização do banco.